# Need to schedule a method excecution in asp .net

Tags: c#

I am creating a web application in which I need to allow the user to schedule the excecution of a task.
I have gone through the various threads for scheduling the task but all of them are using windows service that I am not aware of. Moreover I cannot install visual studio in the server systems due to budget constraints.
Is there a way to create a method that runs a scheduler in a background thread in the asp .net application.Any code sample will be of great help.

Comment: aside from using the built-in Windows task scheduler to launch IE? You can use that to schedule execution of a page. Ex. <path to IE>\iexplore.exe %1 <url of ASP.Net page>

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way to go. If you need a scheduled task you should create a console application and run it using the Windows task scheduler.

You could create an application that sends an email to the user with a link to the page where the task is supposed to be done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what i am doing is actually an enhancement to a current project.
so my current application is a web application from which i need to schedule a task

Comment: I've just added a couple of lines to my answer, unfortunately creating a scheduled task on a web application doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to understand is that ASP.NET is intended to service requests from the network.
Everything in it is geared towards that. So, yes, you can run background tasks, but there are a number of caveats and gotcha's.

For instance, IIS will shut down your ASP.NET application if it does not receive any requests for some period. Also, your Application may be restarted without warning, if it detects changes to the file system. So, running code will be aborted.

That's not to say you can't work around these, but it's really not the best fit for scheduled task execution.

Your best bet would be to store the details of the task in a database, and then using either a single always-running Windows Service (really not that difficult to do, there are plenty of examples), or a console application (as suggested) scheduled manually to run regularly, to execute these tasks.

You may find that a library such as Quartz.NET may be of help scheduling/running these tasks.